# Array.from(string) method not working in Google Script

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to do a very simplified Caesar Cipher, but for this, I need to convert a string to an array. I used

```
 var i = Array.from('string')`
```

but google does not recognize this as a valid method.

Is there a way around this? I want to make it so a string

```
'Hello World'
```

becomes an array of each character

```
[H, e, l, l, o, , W, o, r, l, d]
```

Google doesn't recognize the `.toCharArray()` method either, nor the `split("")` or `split("(?!^)")`

**RESOLVED** I used `var ui = DocumentApp.getUi();  var input = ui.prompt("");  var array = input.getResponseText().split("");`

Comment: `array.split('');` - but Chrome should support `Array.from` after v45.

Comment: Array.from("Hello World")  works in Chrome 45+ https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from

Comment: I'm currently working with Google Script, a program much like Google Docs or Google Slides, and it doesn't recognize either of these as a valid method. Could it be because I am not using a raw string, but an object that contains a string?

Comment: @Blake what kind of object are you using to encapsulate string value?

Comment: toCharArray is not JavaScript - split("(?!^)") is not a valid regex

Comment: I'm using a `.prompt` string, so that whatever string a user returns, it will create an array of each character

Comment: `var x = prompt("","Hello World"); alert(x?x.split(""):"Nothing entered")` works in all browsers

Comment: I only tried those as a last resort after finding similar questions to mine on this site. I figured it wasn't java, but it looked close enough to give it a try

Comment: JavaScript is NOT JAVA!

Comment: Has this question been resolved? If so, please select an answer or post a solution you may have found elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

You can run `split` directly on the string.

```
var i = "hello world".split("");
```

Comment: He is prompting. It is a GoogleScript App

Comment: Run it off the response of the prompt then, the point is to not use the Array class, since Array.from isn't working. --- `input.getResponseText().split("")`

Comment: I would think Array.from(input.getResponseText()) would work too

Comment: One would think. Running the code in Google Script, though, it's complaining that "from isn't a function of Object", or something like that.

Comment: Christian Hain's method for using the input.getResponseText().split("") worked wonderfully, thank you for your responses

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a `.prompt` to ask user for input you need to store it into a variable.

```js
var ui = DocumentApp.getUi();
var input = ui.prompt('') //...

// Then if you want to access the input text
var array = Array.from(input.getResponseText());
```

Take a look at google's documentation for Google Apps Script https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/prompt-response